# CodeIgniter Routing

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes

I'm trying to build a short URI service with CI just so I can learn CI faster 
anyway .. I got stuck at the routing 
i hid the index.php  then added the following route  `$route['([A-z0-9]{4})'] = "/forward/redirect/$1";`

but it just shows my default controller

I also tried with HTaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9]{4})$ /forward/redirect/$1 [NC]
```

It gives an error for not having any passed data 
any help is appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally got it working >_>

routes file contains this

```
$route['([A-z0-9]{4})'] = "/forward/redirect/$1";
```

htaccess contains this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9]{4})$ index.php/forward/redirect/?$1 [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|(.*).js|(.*).css|(.*).jpg|(.*).png)
//added (.*) so resources could be loaded properly :)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no physical path `/forward/redirect/`, you should redirect to the "catch all" index.php file in the root and input the path as parameter:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9]{4})$ /index.php/forward/redirect/$1 [NC]
```

Or you can leave the rule as is and append another rule (this way you will have two rewriting cycles, the first one will rewrite to `/forward/redirect/asdf` and then the second one rewrites to `index.php/forward/redirect/asdf`:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9]{4})$ /forward/redirect/$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: See the Apache log files. Enable "RewriteLog" and see what's there (more info -http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteLog)